# Convert a small image into a larger version in terms of filesize

Tags: images, conversion

I need to create a large image (in filesize) using a small one as a source.

Images on my website are being hotlinked and I'd like to get revenge. I want to replace the hotlinked images with one huge image (several megs in size) and serve that to them instead.

I've found a good image, but it's less than 100kb, and I'm already using it to serve up to the hotlinkers.

How can I convert this image to one that is several megs its current filesize?

Comment: Why not make it a normal image showing some text that hotlinking is not allowed? Now you're punishing the website *visitors* (and also leaving them wondering *what* happened), not the people who are guilty of the actual hotlinking.

Comment: imho, the site owner will eventually punished from lossing visitors

Comment: You run the risk of burning a lot of your own bandwidth -- be sure to keep an eye on it when you start serving up these huge images.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I know you are doing a tag cleanup, but there is barely a single post on the front page that is not a edit by you. Slow down man!

Comment: Thats the whole point of this activity - We can clear these out a *lot* faster If we're not self rate limiting. I'm not *just* tag editing - I'm also fixing errors as I come across them *and* reviewing/accepting tag edits. Help would be nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagemagick will do it.

```
mogrify -resize 2000% picture.jpg
```

Comment: wow! that more getting on to me rather than the bad hotlinkers.

it almost take down my laptop. mouse can hardly move. ctrl-c and closing the konsole takes few minutes to be effective.

any other ways that's not that heavy on my turion2 cpu?

tnx

Comment: well, i adjust the percentage and here's the result: http://omploader.org/iM3Z5cQ

Comment: Sorry! You did say that the original was LESS than 100k.  Thanks for the good laugh though.

Comment: that's not the original size. the original did less than 100k

Comment: @Denny Aha, while we're at the subject of ethics like hotlinking and putting up innocent visitors with huge images, what about copyright issues then? Though from 1949, your http://omploader.org/iM3Z5cQ might still be copyrighted? http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0041178/ :-)

Comment: i found that on google, lots of sites use it. and didnt see any info about the copyright of the image.

anyway... i'll just seek for other image with clear copyright info for this. tnx

Answer (score -1):

Goatse - or another gross image of the same ilk - is an offensive fun(!) image replacement for unauthorized linking, if you're out for revenge. (And I do mean *offensive*! Don't go looking for this unless you're not easily offended!)
You won't have to pay the data charges to deliver a humungous file, and the linking site owner is likely to gets his/her hand slapped when the complaints start coming in to his/her web host, and you're likely to get a very quick removal of the link.  Just remember to change your own link to a different copy of the proper image!

Comment: nice, but i'm easily offended so i wont seek for this.

Comment: Why would you bring that up in an answer?

Comment: Because it directly addresses the OP's request.  He said he means "to get revenge".